# Lets encrypt and Go

Tags: ssl, go, lets-encrypt

I currently have my letsencrypt certs set up for my domain www.example.com and example.com

When I open my server https://www.example.com works perfectly BUT https://example.com will give me

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I am doing the server the following way

```
if err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(
    ":443",
    "domain-crt.pem",
    "domain-key.pem",
    Route.router,
); err != nil {
    ERROR.Fatal(err)
}
```

This gives me no errors and with the www the website works fine. The .pem files are not encrypted and the ListenAndServeTLS doesn't return any error.

Comment: This sounds more like DNS and IP.  Connection refused means that there's no TCP listener on the port (or a facsimile thereof).  Do example.com and www.example.com resolve to the same IP?

Comment: Could it be my DNS setup? I have A record with host www pointing to my ip and URL redirect record with @ host pointing to www.example.com

Comment: "URL redirect records" are a fiction that domain providers use to redirect folks (i.e. that's not an actual DNS thing).  Basically what happens is that your A record points to THEIR server, which terminates the first connection and serves an HTTP 302 or similar to go to the address you actually want.  In this case, your domain provider isn't providing SSL, so your connect refused.  Usually I put the A record for the IP on @ and use a CNAME to redirect "www" -> @ and that's the sanest thing to do if you can.

Comment: I can change it yeah. But on my provider it says that "Setting up CNAME for a naked domain may affect email service" should I worry about this?

Comment: If @ is an actual A record, www is a CNAME, you have one or more @ MX records, and you are only using user@example.com (and not user@www.example.com) email addresses, you should be fine.  PM me with your domain and I'll hit it with host(1) and see if there are any obvious red flags.

Comment: I dont think stackoverflow supports private messages. I cant add a CNAME record for www -> @ with the error @ should not be an IP/URL for CNAME

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122945/discussion-between-alvaro-carvajal-nakosmai-and-bj-black).

Answer (score 0):

This as told in the comments was a DNS error caused by using URL REDIRECT record

I simply added an A record pointint @ to my IP and the same for www